# TFS 2010 Controller integration to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

We have migrated TFS2010 to TFS2015sp3 and we would like to use the existing TFS2010 build controller & agents (XAML) with TFS2015.

As a sample test, we did a clone of the existing TFS2010 controller and on the new machine we pointed the Project collections to the new TFS2015 URL.

I see the build controller and Agents in running state, but when I queue the build it keeps on waiting for build agent, even though the agents are online.

Comment: what have you done?  show code...

Comment: On the cloned TFS 2010build machine , we pointed the controller  to the new TFS 2015 Collections. when build queued , it never picks up the build agent. but I could see both controller and agent are online.I tried to delete the controller , its giving error " controller currently reserved for a build"

Comment: @MohanKrishna Why not just set up a new build controller and agent against your TFS2015 server? And what's the detail mean of clone in your question? Did you just mean the same configuration?

Comment: thank you ,can i  go with TFS2010 controller or i can  install TFS2015 XAML controller , because my builds are in XAML. please suggest. My meaning of Clone , is a complete machine snapshot , including the Configurations

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2015 **still support XAML Builds** as long as you use TFS2010/TFS2013 XAML Build controller.

Please make sure your build control version are the same as build agent version. So if you are using TFS2010 build control, you should also using TFS2010 build agent.

You could also create a new build control TFS2015 and build agent 2015, test if the build works properly.

Even though the build agent and control is online, you should also double confirm you have selected the right one in the drop list when you queue the build.

[image]

---

Besides, please also verify that your controller has "Maximum number of concurrently running builds" set to a number higher than 0. The default to number of agents can sometimes go wrong.

You set this on the controller properties in the TFS admin console.

You can also try remove the agent from the controller and add it again.

Comment: Thanks Patrick,sorry i missed to respond back on this thread. Reinstalling the controller and agent helped to resolve the issue.